# Redirect wget screen output to a log file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, wget

First of all, thank you everyone for your help. I have the following file that contains a series of URL:

```
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhi    https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/003/717/755/GCF_003717755.1_ASM371775v1/GCF_003717755.1_ASM371775v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Paratyphi_A  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/818/115/GCF_000818115.1_ASM81811v1/GCF_000818115.1_ASM81811v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Paratyphi_B  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/018/705/GCF_000018705.1_ASM1870v1/GCF_000018705.1_ASM1870v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/011/182/555/GCA_011182555.2_ASM1118255v2/GCA_011182555.2_ASM1118255v2_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/006/945/GCF_000006945.2_ASM694v2/GCF_000006945.2_ASM694v2_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_diarizonae    https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/003/324/755/GCF_003324755.1_ASM332475v1/GCF_003324755.1_ASM332475v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_arizonae  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/635/675/GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02/GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_bongori  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/006/113/225/GCF_006113225.1_ASM611322v2/GCF_006113225.1_ASM611322v2_translated_cds.faa.gz
```

And I have to download the url using wget I have already achieve to download the URL but the typicall output in shell appears:

```
--2021-04-23 02:49:00--  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/635/675/GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02/GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02_translated_cds.faa.gz
Reusing existing connection to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1097880 (1,0M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02_translated_cds.faa.gz’

GCA_900635675.1_31885_G0 100%[=================================>]   1,05M  2,29MB/s    in 0,5s    

2021-04-23 02:49:01 (2,29 MB/s) - ‘GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02_translated_cds.faa.gz’ saved [1097880/1097880]
```

I want to redirect that output to a `log file`. Also as the files download, I want to decompress them, because they are zip in .gz. My code is the following

```
cat $ncbi_urls_file | while read line
do
    echo " Downloading fasta files from NCBI..."
    awk '{print $2}' | wget -i- 
done
```

Comment: Where are you using `line` in the loop...?

Comment: To read each line from the document

Comment: I believe they're asking where in the loop you actually do anything with said line. You're piping `$2` to `wget` rather than `$line`, so you never actually do anything with `$line` after reading into it

Comment: `wget "$(echo "$line" | cut -f2-)" 2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard output can be redirected to a file in bash using the `>>` operator (for appending to the file) or the `>` operator (for truncating / overwriting the file). e.g.

```
echo hello >> log.txt
```

will append "hello" to log.txt. If you still want to be able to see the output in your terminal and *also* write it to a log file, you can use `tee`:

```
echo hello | tee.txt
```

However, `wget` outputs most of its basic progress information through standard error rather than standard output. This is actually a very common practice. Displaying progress information often involves special characters to overwrite lines (e.g. to update a progress bar), change terminal colors, etc. Terminals can process these characters sensibly in real time, but it often does not make much sense to store them in a file. For this reason, such kinds of incremental progress output are often separated from other output which is more sensible to store in a log file to make them easier to redirect accordingly, and hence incremental progress information is often output through standard error rather than standard output.

However, you can still redirect standard error to a log file:

```
wget example.com 2>> log.txt
```

Or using `tee`:

```
wget example.com 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

(`2>&1` redirects standard error through standard output, which is then piped to `tee`).

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know how to decompress?

Comment: `.gz` is a gzip / gunzip file extension, so you'll probably want to use gzip / gunzip to decompress it. Some quick research on how to decompress `gz` files on Linux will probably help you.

Answer (score 2):

*wget*

`wget` does have options allowing logging to files, from [`man wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

```
Logging and Input File Options

-o logfile
--output-file=logfile
    Log all messages to logfile. The messages are normally reported to standard error. 
-a logfile
--append-output=logfile
    Append to logfile. This is the same as -o, only it appends to logfile instead of overwriting the old log file. If logfile does not exist, a new file is created. 
-d
--debug
    Turn on debug output, meaning various information important to the developers of Wget if it does not work properly. Your system administrator may have chosen to compile Wget without debug support, in which case -d will not work. Please note that compiling with debug support is always safe---Wget compiled with the debug support will not print any debug info unless requested with -d. 
-q
--quiet
    Turn off Wget's output. 
-v
--verbose
    Turn on verbose output, with all the available data. The default output is verbose. 
-nv
--no-verbose
    Turn off verbose without being completely quiet (use -q for that), which means that error messages and basic information still get printed.
```

You would need to experiment to got what you need, if you need all logs in single file use `-a log.out`, which will cause wget to append logging information to said file and not writing to `stderr`.

Comment: This is better than my answer; I learned something new. +1